# Post processing the controller response with a plug in phoenix

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

How can I create a plug that e.g. turns the `body` of the response to upper case if the `content-type` is `text/plain`? In other middlewares you'd call `resp = next(conn, params)` and then modify `resp` but I haven't seen this in plug.

Answer (score 14):

You can define a plug that uses [register_before_send/2](http://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Conn.html#register_before_send/2) and check the `content-type` header of the response (please note that Plug expects headers to be lowercase). A naive implementation (no error checking) would be:

```
defmodule Plug.UpperCaser do
  @behaviour Plug

  import Plug.Conn

  def init(opts), do: opts

  def call(conn, _opts) do
    register_before_send(conn, fn(conn) ->
      [content_type | _tail] = get_resp_header(conn, "content-type")
      if String.contains?(content_type, "text/plain") do
        resp(conn, conn.status, conn.resp_body |> to_string |> String.upcase)
      else
        conn
      end
    end)
  end
end
```

[resp/3](http://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Conn.html#resp/3) is used as [send_resp/3](http://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Conn.html#send_resp/3) will cause an infinite loop and you will have to restart your server.